# LG Monitor not working with 75hz

Tags: multiple-monitors, monitor

[image]

I have LG 34WL500 and it works fine with 60hz settings, but when I set 75hz the screen remains black. Has anyone experienced similar issue? Am not sure if additional drivers are needed for this monitor. Thank you in advance for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Found my solution - enable hdmi compatibility mode on my monitor

Comment: In monitor settings, there is on/off for hdmi compatibility mode